# Writing css for Angular 2 View encapsulation via styleUrl

Tags: css, angular, encapsulation

I am making a simple hello world app (currently migrating from angular 1) I used angular-cli to generate my components and it created a stylesheet and linked it in my component via styleUrls. None of my styles apply the way I think they are supposed to unless I do "viewEncapsulation.none." Is there something I'm missing? Or is there a better way to write out css for this?

If I use the default encapsulation ( ViewEncapsulation.Emulated or even native) my styles don't show up at all.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';  

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
}
}
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
.app-header{
    display: block;
    opacity:0.2;
}
```

Comment: I edited my response. Have you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this css:

```
:host() {
    display: block;
    opacity:0.2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set `module:module.id` in the component declaration for angular to search for the file in the right location. Have you verified that the CSS gets loaded in the non working case?

I am assuming you are using the `app-header` css somewhere in `header.component.html`? Try the below code.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';  

@Component({
  module: module.id,
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so do put this in my decorator? 

moduleId: 'app-header',

Comment: angular-cli does not use the module Id.

Comment: Can you put the content of your component HTML file in the question as well so that I can give a more detailed and complete example.

Answer (score 0):

Don't manipulate the component tag, this tag scope belongs to the parent component who uses it. manipulate only tags inside your html template component.